# How does `sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV` work?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, cross-validation, xgboost

I am making a binary classifier with unbalanced classes (of ratio 1:10). I tried KNN, RFs, and XGB classifier. I am getting the best precision-recall tradeoff and F1 score among them from XGB classifer(perhaps because size of dataset is very less - `(1900,19)`)

So after checking error plots for XGB, i decided to go for `RandomizedSearchCV()` from sklearn for parameter tuning of my XGB classifier. Based on another answer on stackexchange, this is my code :

```
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV, StratifiedKFold
score_arr = []
clf_xgb = XGBClassifier(objective = 'binary:logistic')
param_dist = {'n_estimators': [50, 120, 180, 240, 400],
              'learning_rate': [0.01, 0.03, 0.05],
              'subsample': [0.5, 0.7],
              'max_depth': [3, 4, 5],
              'min_child_weight': [1, 2, 3], 
              'scale_pos_weight' : [9]
            }
clf = RandomizedSearchCV(clf_xgb, param_distributions = param_dist, n_iter = 25, scoring = 'precision', error_score = 0, verbose = 3, n_jobs = -1)
print(clf)
numFolds = 6
folds = StratifiedKFold(n_splits = numFolds, shuffle = True)

estimators = []
results = np.zeros(len(X))
score = 0.0
for train_index, test_index in folds.split(X_train, y_train):
    print(train_index)
    print(test_index)
    _X_train, _X_test = X.iloc[train_index,:], X.iloc[test_index,:]
    _y_train, _y_test = y.iloc[train_index].values.ravel(), y.iloc[test_index].values.ravel()
    clf.fit(_X_train, _y_train, eval_metric="error", verbose=True)

    estimators.append(clf.best_estimator_)
    results[test_index] = clf.predict(_X_test)
    score_arr.append(f1_score(_y_test, results[test_index]))
    score += f1_score(_y_test, results[test_index])
score /= numFolds
```

So `RandomizedSearchCV` actually selects the classifier and then in kfolds it got fit and predict result on the validation set. **Note that** i have given `X_train` and `y_train` in kfolds split, so that i have a seperate `test` dataset for testing the final algorithm.

Now, the problem is, if you actually looks the `f1-score` in each kfold iteration, it is like this `score_arr = [0.5416666666666667, 0.4, 0.41379310344827586, 0.5, 0.44, 0.43478260869565216]` .

But when I test `clf.best_estimator_` as my model, on my `test` dataset, it gives `f1-score` of `0.80` and with `{'precision': 0.8688524590163934, 'recall': 0.7571428571428571}` precision and recall.

How come my score while validation is low and what has happened now on testset? Is my model correct or Did i missed something?

P.S. - *Taking the parameters of `clf.best_estimator_`, i fitted them seperately on my training data using `xgb.cv`, then also the `f1-score` was near `0.55`. I think this might be due to differences between training approaches of `RandomizedSearchCV` and `xgb.cv`. Please tell me if plots or more info needed.*

**Update** : I am attaching error plots of train and test `aucpr` and `classification accuracy`for the generated model. The plot is generated by running `model.fit()` only once (justifying the values of `score_arr`).
[image]

Comment: can you increase the k-value to very high number like 20 and see what happens?

Comment: Yes, i tried with 22 k-folds and it's only increasing the precision and recall at test set and similar set of variable values in `score_arr`

Answer (score 1):

Randomized search on hyperparameters.

While using a grid of parameter settings is currently the most widely used method for parameter optimization, other search methods have more favorable properties. RandomizedSearchCV implements a randomized search over parameters, where each setting is sampled from a distribution over possible parameter values. This has two main benefits over an exhaustive search:

```
A budget can be chosen independently of the number of parameters and possible values.

Adding parameters that do not influence the performance does not decrease efficiency.
```

If all parameters are presented as a list, sampling without replacement is performed. If at least one parameter is given as a distribution, sampling with replacement is used. It is highly recommended to use continuous distributions for continuous parameters.

for more (Reference ): [SKLEARN documentation for RandomizedSearchCV](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV.html)